# Proper way to close NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am using server client architecture in my application.

I am using NSURLConnection class,now suppose i am sending multiple requests in for loop and using async connection with delegate methods.So my question is
after I got response from server do I need to close connection manually and make that object null.

I am asking because on server there is constraint on maximum connections to be made and if that connection limit exceeds  I have to restart server and I can not change maximum connection limit.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not needed as `NSURLConnection` will close the connection by itself when an error occurs or the data has loaded.

If you wish to monitor what actually happens, I suggest looking at [Technical Q&A QA1176](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECIOSPACKETTRACING). It describes how you can set up an environment to monitor each packet that is sent by an iPhone. Then you can verify the behavior of `NSURLConnection` yourself.

Comment: Thanks .That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to release the connection is to set it to be `nil` along with the property used to receive data from the connection:

```
theConnection = nil;
receivedData = nil;
```

This is from the [URL Session Programming Guide in the section Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).

> Release the connection and the data object by setting the properties (declared elsewhere) to nil. Note that a real-world app usually requires the delegate to manage more than one connection at a time, so these lines would typically be replaced by code to iterate through whatever data structures you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Please used this..may be helped

```
[self.connection cancel];
self.connection = nil;
```